# vendor directory missing from docker container after composer install GitLab CI/CD

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I'm trying to make a GitLab pipeline, but for some reason after I run:

```
- docker run image composer install
- docker run image ls
```

It shows every file of my project, except the vendor directory, even though in the job logs I see that the dependencies did install.

```
CONDUCT.md
CONTRIBUTING.md
Dockerfile
LICENSE.md
README.md
TODO.md
Vagrantfile
composer.json
composer.lock
config
data
html
module
phpcs.xml
phpunit.xml.dist
public
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this a Docker problem, or a Composer problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

`Docker run` will run an image into a unique container. When the command finishes, your container will become "completed" and anything you have executed is available in the volume of that container.
When you executed `docker run` again, another container was created, so the previous command was never executed in that container (using the container's volume).

If you would like to compare it to Virtual Machines (to understand it better), every `docker run` command will spin up a different virtual machine. And when the command is done the virtual machine is suspended.

Based on your question, I'm not sure what you are trying to do, so I'll just describe 2 situations.

If you just want to run commands in your image, but not want to build a new image. You should add this to your gitlab-ci.yaml file. It will run the commands in your image.

```yaml
#.gitlab-ci.yaml
your_job: 
   image: [your_image]
   script: 
      - composer install 
      - ls
```

If you want to build an image instead, you have to add the commands to a Dockerfile. And then just build the image in the pipeline.

```
# Dockerfile

FROM   [your_image] 

WORKDIR  /var/www

COPY   . . 

RUN    composer install \ 
       && ls
```

You can then add the following script to your pipeline

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
your_job:
   script:
      - docker build -t [repository]:[tag]
      - docker push [repository]:[tag]
```

I've also seen some people running `composer install` outside the docker build scope, and then copy the project and vendor directory.  Usually because they need different system packages, but you can use multi-staged docker builds for that.

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do is make a pipeline, which runs phpcs, to check for violations of the coding standard. Does that mean that I need to make 2 stages - build and test? In the build stage run - docker build -t [name] and in the test run composer install, phpcs?

Comment: When I try to do this: 

`stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:  php-image

build:
  tags: [docker-bind]
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$SSH_KEY" -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME .
  
test:
  tags: [docker-bind]
  stage: test
  script:
    - phpcs`

theres still no vendor directory.

Comment: That's because each job runs in a different "scope", in theory different jobs can even run on a different runners(/servers)!  So you need a shared "state". In your case, it's the image you've built.  I don't even think you need a (custom) docker image at all based on your answer. But I don't know your situation. Are you using the image to deploy to production too? Are you running on gitlab cloud or private?  
Based on that I could give the appropriate answer with the most performance

Comment: In my case, I recognized a difference between Docker on GitLab Runner and Docker on localhost. A COPY statement overwrites my vendor dir in my Dockerfile. On my localhost, it works well, but not on my GitLab Runner with Docker.
By changing the order of COPY, it works correctly on both systems.